# Association off 3 models by common column

Tags: ruby-on-rails-5.2

I have 3 models `Company, Officer, Documents` the data for them is extracted from a Api with Httparty one at the time. Every model has a `company_number` attribute(`type :string` some of them start with 0 or letters) that is the same in all models. Is it possible to add association based on the `company_number`?
i want to be able to do `company.officers and company.documents` as per `Company has_many :officers has_many :documents` respectiv `belongs_to :company`

thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

thank you, I resolved the problem by renaming the columns `company_number` in `officer and documents models` to `company_id` and added `htm association` in models